# Phonegap application displays all angular variables

Tags: angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

[image: Displaying all angular variables on application load]

The phonegap application loads properly but the app displays all the angular variables for a fraction of second and then the app is being displayed in actual format.

Why does this happens? Is it because of too many contents on the page?

Comment: Show your json response and html part

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: It seems that the DOM element aren't getting loaded as fast as the app renders it.

Comment: You can check the coding snippet @ http://pastebin.com/cwyQdFGX